# How to avoid returning user password in Symfony 3 via JSON

Tags: php, json, rest, symfony

I am developing a Symfony app with a REST API integrated but I'm facing a problem, when returning an user entity as JSON through an API request it returns the user password and despite being encrypted I would like to avoid it.

My user entity is:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use AppBundle\Util\Language;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->isActive = true;
    }


    // Functions and parameters

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public
    function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get password
     *
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    // More functions and parameters

    /** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
    public
    function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            $this->isActive,
            $this->createdAt,
            $this->lastLogin,
        ));
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
    public
    function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            $this->isActive,
            $this->createdAt,
            $this->lastLogin,
            ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }
}
```

The User repository

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Repository;

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User\UserLoaderInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class UserRepository extends EntityRepository implements UserLoaderInterface
{
    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->where('u.username = :username OR u.email = :email')
            ->setParameter('username', $username)
            ->setParameter('email', $username)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult();
    }
}
```

I have an static method to build API responses

```
public static function createSuccessfulresponse($entity, $entityName, $responseCode, $userLocale = "en", $responseMsg = "")
{
    $defResponseMsg = ($responseMsg != "" ? $responseMsg : ApiResponseCode::getMsg($responseCode, $userLocale));
    $responseArray = array();
    $responseArray['responseCode'] = $responseCode;
    $responseArray['responseMsg'] = $defResponseMsg;
    $responseArray['userLocale'] = $userLocale;
    if ($entity != null) {
        $responseArray[$entityName] = $entity;
    }
    return ApiResponseHelper::serializeResponse($responseArray);
}
```

The response serializer

```
private static function serializeResponse($responseArray)
{
    $encoders = array(new JsonEncoder());
    $normalizers = array(new ObjectNormalizer());
    $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
    return $serializer->serialize($responseArray, 'json');
}
```

And one of the API calls which returns an `user` entity (there are more)

```
/**
 * @Route("/api/url/{uid}" )
 * @Method({"GET"})
 */
public function getByUidAction($uid)
{
    $user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entity = $entityManager->getRepository('AppBundle:Workday')->findOneBy(['uid' => $uid, 'user' => $user]);
    if($entity != null){
        return new Response(ApiResponseHelper::createSuccessfulresponse($entity, "workday", ApiResponseCode::SUCCESS_FETCH_WORKDAY, $user->getLocale()));
    }else{
        return new Response(ApiResponseHelper::createSuccessfulresponse(null, "workday", ApiResponseCode::ERROR_EXISTS_WORKDAY, $user->getLocale()));
    }
}
```

This is one JSON response from the above method

```
{
    "responseCode": "successfulResponseCode",
    "responseMsg": "Data received",
    "userLocale": "es",
    "workday": {
        "id": 10,
        ... so many data
        "job": {
            "id": 11,
            .. more json data
        },
        "user": {
            "username": "amendez",
            "password": "encrypted_password",
            ... more data
        },
        ... and more data
    }
}
```

As you can see I receive a JSON object with the user which contains its encrypted password and many other data, my goal is to avoid returning the password key and value.

Does somebody know how could I achieve it?

Comment: Have you tried taking the password out of the serialize function and unserialize function on the User entity?

Comment: Yes, I tried it without success

Comment: The OP would need it in the serialize method to retain consistency with FOSUserBundle or the default Firewall Entity Provider. https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/entity_provider.html

Comment: @fyrye it is something I didn't try, I will do it and let you know, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to define the Serializer groups with the desired getters assigned. See: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#attributes-groups.

The preferred (best-practice) method would be to assign the desired groups.

```
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
{        
    /**
     * @Groups({"api"})
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }


    //...    

    /**
     * Get password
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }
}
```

---

*Edited for easier use of Serializer service*

In your `app/config/config.yml` enable annotations, which in-turn enables the serializer service.

```
#config.yml
framework:
    #...
    serializer:
        enable_annotations: true
```

Now you can call the Serializer service directly or use DI in your custom services.

```
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

private static function serializeResponse($responseArray)
{
     $serializer = $this->container->get('serializer');

     return $serializer->serialize($responseArray, JsonEncoder::FORMAT, array(
        'groups' => array('api'),
        'json_encode_options' => JsonResponse::DEFAULT_ENCODING_OPTIONS
    ));
}
```

---

To manually use the Serializer Component with groups.

```
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Mapping\Factory\ClassMetadataFactory;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Mapping\Loader\AnnotationLoader;

private static function serializeResponse($responseArray)
{
    $classMetadataFactory = new ClassMetadataFactory(new AnnotationLoader(new AnnotationReader()));

    $normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer($classMetadataFactory);
    $encoder = new JsonEncoder();
    $serializer = new Serializer(array($normalizer), array($encoder));

    return $serializer->serialize($responseArray, JsonEncoder::FORMAT, array('groups' => array('api')));
}
```

---

Alternatively you should be able to set it as part of the ignored attributes. See: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#ignoring-attributes

```
private static function serializeResponse($responseArray)
{
    $normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer();
    $normalizer->setIgnoredAttributes(array('password'));

    $encoder = new JsonEncoder();
    $serializer = new Serializer(array($normalizer), array($encoder));

    return $serializer->serialize($responseArray, JsonEncoder::FORMAT);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @fyrye I tried the second approach and it works, so I suppose the first one works too because it is the same but in another way. I will try it because as you say it is the recommended way to do it, if I find any flag I will let you know. I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: No problem. The reason it is recommended by Symfony is that your declaration of the available group contexts is in a central location. So it's much easier to maintain, troubleshoot, and validate.  As opposed to it being scattered throughout your controllers and services as manually ignored. Say when making another API serialized call and forgetting that password should be ignored.

Comment: Yeah I see, I prefer to do it easier to maintain as possible so I think I will change it to the other approach. Thank you again for the help and nice info

Comment: @AlbertoMéndez I added an easier method of using the serializer with the groups annotation.